# Mocking Filtered Data in C# with MSTest

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, mstest

I'm new to C#, I'm attempting to mock filtered data in C# unit tests using MSTest for a service that retrieves student data from a database. The code below successfully mocks the entire student data list but fails to properly filter the data according to specified criteria.

```
public class NewRequestServiceTests
{
    private readonly NewRequestService _newRequestService;
    private readonly Mock<DatabaseContext> _databaseContext;

    private StudentData _studentDataDE;
    private StudentData _studentDataFR  ;

    public NewRequestServiceTests()
    {
        _databaseContext = new Mock<DatabaseContext>();
        _newRequestService = new NewRequestService(_databaseContext.Object);
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
       _InitializeTestDataBeforeTests();  //Initialize dummy data
       _databaseContext.Setup(dc => dc.StudentData).ReturnsDbSet(new List<StudentData>
           {
               _studentDataDE, // initialized in the _InitializeTestDataBeforeTests() method
               _studentDataFR  // initialized in the _InitializeTestDataBeforeTests() method
           });
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetNewRequest_ValidResponse()
    {
         var studentId = 1;
         var response = await _newRequestService.GetNewRequest(studentId , new List<int>());
         // Asserts
         // ...
    } 
}
```

In another method, the data is filtered using the following code:

```
var studentDataList = await _databaseContext.StudentData
        .Include(e => e.ApplicableEducationalLegislationBasis)
        .Where(sd => sd.StudentId == id
                     && sd.ApplicableEducationalLegislationBasis.IsActive == true
                     && sd.AssessingSchoolAuthorityId != userAuthority.Code)
        .ToListAsync();
```

This code doesn't throw an error, but it returns an empty list. Does anyone have any ideas or a related topic?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The obvious answer is that there is no data that meets the criteria. So it is up to you to look into that first.

Comment: You mocked with "moq"? And ReturnsDbSet is something written by you?

Comment: God... I've been looking at this issue for so long that this did not even occur to me, in the data initialization there was a field missing and I never noticed...

Thank you very much @topsail.

Comment: @Ralf it was my bad I forgot a field in the data initialization and I never noticed it.

Comment: Is the `DatabaseContext` type something from your database library? Why do you want to mock it?